ExcelJS ignores date format
I am trying to set format to date column, but it looks like excelJS is ignoring my format and puts its own. I read that {useStyles: true} should be used, but all examples were including streams, which I do not use.
My code:
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet1');
worksheet.columns = [{
        header: 'Date',
        key: 'date',
        style: {
          numFmt: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        }
      },
      {
        header: 'startedAt',
        key: 'startedAt'
      },
     ...

]
cosnt worksheetRow = {
   date: row.visitDate // Date object,
   startedAt: moment(row.startedAt).format('L') // string value
   ...
}

worksheet.addRow(worksheetRow).commit();

Output in excel file is:

It looks like excelJS is ignoring my format and puts its own.
StartedAt is formatted ok, but it is stored as a string, so customers are not able to work with that column as it is Date, e.g. change formats.
I would like the format be Date with some specified format.
